# Magit - Undo last commit - History Manipulation

Tags: magit, git

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-last-commits-in-git) has the best solutions/approaches to undo last commits.

I started using Magit a couple a weeks ago and after looking through all its documentation I still don't have a definitive/best way to undo a mistakenly committed change.

For example:
For undo and redo the last commit we can use:

```
$ git commit -m "Something terribly misguided"
$ git reset HEAD~
<< edit files as necessary >>
$ git add ... 
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD # To keep the same commit message
```

What should be the best workflow to reproduce this procedure using [Magit](https://magit.vc/)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `magit-reset` (bound by default to <kbd>x</kbd>).  The
commit at point will be used as the default for the prompt, but you
can enter any revision value you'd like ("HEAD~" here).

The resetting commands are described in the "Resetting" section of the
manual: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Resetting.html

To reuse the commit message, you can use the `=C` option in the commit
popup.  Unforuntately, the prompt doesn't currently offer any
completion values (I think it should probably at least offer
`ORIG_HEAD`), but before resetting you can put the hash of the current
commit in the kill ring (e.g., with <kbd>C-w</kbd> on the "Head:" line
of the status buffer) and then, after resetting, yank it as the value
for the `=C` option.

---

Some additional comments:

- Instead of using `=C`, you may find it more convient to start off
  the commit (<kbd>cc</kbd>) and then use `git-commit-prev-message`
  (<kbd>M-p</kbd>) to cycle through previous messages.
- If you are only modifying the last commit, you can tack on staged
  changes to the previous commit with `magit-commit-amend`
  (<kbd>ca</kbd>) or `magit-commit-extend` (<kbd>ce</kbd>).  (The
  latter reuses the commit message, bypassing the COMMIT_EDITMSG
  buffer.)